# Substituting the conservation of angular momentum into the Binet formula results in contradiction

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, energy-conservation, centrifugal-force

**Background Information**

The lagrangian of a particle in a central force field $V(r)$ is
$$
L=\frac12m(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta\dot\varphi^2)-V(r).
$$
The particle must move in a plane, so the coordinate system can always be chosen such that $\dot\varphi=0$. The motion is restricted to be 2D. Then
$$
L=\frac12m(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\theta^2)-V(r).\tag{1}
$$
The Euler-Lagrange Equation for $r$ gives
$$
m(\ddot r-r\dot \theta^2)+V'(r)=0.\tag{2}
$$
With some trick one derives [Binet equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation), but the formula itself is not the point of this post.

---

Canonical variable $\theta$ doesn't appear in Lagrangian (1), so the canonical momentum
is conserved, too. Set it to be
$$
p_\theta=mr^2\dot\theta=l=\text{const}.\tag{3}
$$
The Lagrangian becomes
$$
L=\frac12m\dot r^2+\frac{l}{2mr^2}-V(r).
$$
The problem is now 1D. Applying Euler-Lagrange Equation again, we will get
$$
m\ddot r+\frac{l}{mr^3}+V'(r)=0.\tag{4}
$$

---

**Question**

Eq (2) is not consistent with Eq (4), since Eq(3) holds. What's wrong? Thanks for answering.

Comment: You cannot use a conservation law in the action before deriving the equations of motion, since $l$ itself depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: @Hossein but in Eq(1) I used  $p_\varphi＝0$, otherwise an extral item  will go into Eq(2), and $p_\theta$ is not conserved. Is this process legal?

Comment: The conserved momentum $p_\theta$ can be regarded as a constraint on the particle. So the system has only one free variable, which can be chosen to be $r$.

Comment: For $(\varphi,p_{\varphi})$ the coordinate is constant and the momentum is zero. For $(\theta,p_{\theta})$ neither the coordinate $\theta$ and the momentum $p_\theta$ are not zero. In fact, for the special case of $p_{\theta}=0$ where the motion is actually along a line, you can substitute in the Lagrangian and you will get the correct equations of motion.

Comment: @Hossein You are right, thank you.

Comment: I asked a very similar question several years ago, see here and the very illuminating answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190602/

Comment: [Related 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262183/lagrangian-of-an-effective-potential/262195#262195), [Related 2.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79535/how-do-you-derive-lagranges-equation-of-motion-from-a-routhian/79540#79540) and links therein.