# Disparity in the equations of motion for a particle in a central field

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, centrifugal-force

**Hello**! I am considering the motion of particle in a central field and appear to derive inconsistent equations of motion when the Euler Lagrange equations are applied directly to (1) the Lagrangian  $L(r,\dot r, \dot \phi)$ and (2) when conservation of angular momentum is used eliminate $\dot \phi$ to write $L(r,\dot r)$:

**Method 1:** The Lagrangian for a particle in a central field is
$$ L = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot r^2 + r^2 \dot \phi^2\right) - U(r)$$
Langrange's equation, ${\rm d}(\partial L/\partial \dot q)/{\rm d}t = \partial L/\partial q$, for $q=\phi$ yields conservation of ang. momentum:

\begin{align}
&\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}(mr^2\dot \phi) = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad  mr^2\dot \phi = \text{constant} = M (\text{say})\\
\end{align}
Langrange's equation for $q=r$ becomes 
\begin{align}
m\ddot r = mr\dot \phi^2 - {\rm d}U/{\rm d}r = \frac{M^2}{mr^3} - {\rm d}U/{\rm d}r
\end{align}
where the second equality holds from conservation of ang. momentum.

**Method 2:** Now if we use conservation of ang. momentum $\dot \phi = M/(mr^2)$ to eliminate $\dot \phi$ from our original Lagrangian we have
$$ L = \frac{1}{2}m\dot r^2 + \frac{M^2}{2mr^2} -U(r)$$ 
Lagrange's equation for $r$, ${\rm d}(\partial L/\partial \dot r)/{\rm d}t = \partial L/\partial r$, gives
$$m\ddot r = -\frac{M^2}{mr^3} - {\rm d} U/{\rm d} r$$ 
Compare this to the radial momentum equation of method 1. **Note the difference in sign of the term** $M^2/(mr^3)$**!!**

***Any ideas of how to resolve the disparity?***

**Resolution of Disparity**. Ref: [How can you solve this "paradox"? Central potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83190/how-can-you-solve-this-paradox-central-potential) in particular the answer by @Craig J Copi. Essentially when computing $\partial L/\partial r$ in method 2 one must remember that although $M$ is a constant of the motion ($\dot M = 0$) that $\partial M/\partial r = 2mr\dot \phi = 2M/r \neq 0$

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262183/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83190/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no no no no-no-no!  Plugging in a conservation law to eliminate a variable in the Lagrangian just isn't going to work. The way L varies with r(t) is different from the way it varies with $\dot \phi$, and therein lies all the interesting physics.

Solution: Just don't do Method 2.

Comment: Thank you @DarenW for the reply. Would you mind describing why exactly "Plugging in a conservation law to eliminate a variable in the Lagrangian just isn't going to work" ? Thanks again!