# Reducing the degrees of freedom of a Lagrangian in a spherical potential by using integrals of motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, centrifugal-force, integrals-of-motion

I'm sure I've made a silly mistake here, so I would be very grateful if someone could help me clear it up! Here is my reasoning:

The Lagrangian in a spherical potential is 
$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{m\mathbf{v}^2}{2}-U(r) = \frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2 +r^2\dot{\theta}^2+r^2\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi}^2)-U(r).
$$
Now $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}=0$, so the corresponding momentum $p_\phi=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{\phi}}=mr^2\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi}$ is constant in time. This means that the Lagrangian can instead be written 
$$
\mathcal{L} =\frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2 +r^2\dot{\theta}^2+\underbrace{[r^2\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi}]}_{p_\phi}\dot{\phi})-U(r) =\frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2 +r^2\dot{\theta}^2)-U(r)+\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{m}{2}p_\phi \phi).
$$
Since $p_\phi$ is constant the last term is a total derivative and so can be omitted completely, and the Lagrangian may be written as 
$$
\mathcal{L}’= \frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2 +r^2\dot{\theta}^2)-U(r)
$$
The Lagrangian now has $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}’}{\partial\theta}=0$ which was not true for the original one. Something has clearly gone wrong, but where?

Also, following the same logic for $\theta$ gives that 
$$ 
\mathcal{L}’’= \frac{m\dot{r}^2}{2}-U(r)
$$ 
Which is also wrong - the effective potential energy has the wrong form.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262183/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83190/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lagrangian of an effective potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262183/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point is that one is not allowed to use EOM in the Lagrangian. For such problems one should instead form (minus) the [Routhian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routhian_mechanics) 
$$-R(r,\dot{r};\theta,\dot{\theta};\phi,p_{\phi})~=~L - p_{\phi}\dot\phi~=~ \frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\dot{\theta}^2\right) \color{Red}{-}\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{2mr^2\sin^2\theta} -U(r) $$
by Legendre transforming the [cyclic coordinate](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cyclic_coordinates) $\phi$.

Warning: To forget the minus sign in red is a common mistake, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262183/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83190/2451) related Phys.SE posts. The minus sign is important because it is a centrifugal (rather than a centripetal) potential.