# Rewriting the Lagrangian in terms of the constant(s) of motion doesn't work. Why? (spherical pendulum)

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, centrifugal-force

[image: Spherical Pendulum]

I am trying to solve for the equations of motion to simulate a [spherical pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum). I decided to use the spherical coordinates. The Lagrange equation is,
$$
L=T-V=\frac{1}{2}m\left(l\dot\theta\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}m\left(l\sin\theta\dot\phi\right)^2-\left(-mgl\cos\theta\right),
$$

where $l$ is the length of the rope, $ϕ$ is the angle of the projection of the rope on $x$-$y$ plane with $x$-axis and $θ$ is the angle with the $-z$-axis.

Now, From Noether's theorem, we know that the quantity

$$
J=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}=ml^2\dot{\phi}sin^2\theta
$$
is constant. The equation of motion for $\theta$ follows from the Lagrange's equations and is

$$
ml^2\ddot{\theta}=ml^2\dot{\phi}sin\theta cos\theta-mglsin\theta
$$
We can substitute $\dot{\phi}$ for the constant J in the expression to get an equation entirely in terms of $\theta$ which we choose to write as

$$
\ddot{\theta} = -\frac{\partial V_{eff}}{\partial \theta}
$$

where the effective potential is defined to be

$$
V_{eff}(\theta) = -\frac{g}{l}cos\theta 
+ \frac{J^2}{2m^2l^4}\frac{1}{sin^2\theta}
$$

Now, if I had substituted J for $\dot{\phi}$ directly into the Lagrangian and solved, I would've derived a similar equation as above, but I would've got a minus sign wrong. And apparently the reason is that Lagrange's equations are derived under an assumption that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are independent. I do get that. But since we get $J$ from the Lagrangian, shouldn't substituting $J$ back and solving still work?

I am looking at this as just a mathematical operation and cannot seem to wrap my head around it. Could somebody give me a stronger reason as to why this doesn't work or maybe explain the above reason more explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262183/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83190/2451 and links therein.