# How does effective potential reduce a two variable problem into a single one?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy, centrifugal-force

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential

In this wiki link, They write

$$ E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2  + \frac{1}{2} mr^2 \omega^2  - \frac{GMm}{r}$$

Then they sub

$$ L= mr\omega$$

Which turns the energy expression into,

$$ E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 + \frac{L^2}{2mr^2}  - \frac{GMm}{r}$$

Now, at the end wiki writes that this turns a two variable problem into a single variable one but how?

We still have velocity and radius as varying parameters..

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262183/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83190/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular type of problem, the mechanical energy, *E*, is constant because no external work is done on the system.

What you seem to quote ("They write ...") is not an accurate copy. Rather, they write
$$E = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2\right)-\frac{GmM}{r}.$$

That makes all the difference in the world because, when you change your $v$ to $\dot{r}$ in your last equation, you now have a first-order non-linear differential equation in one variable, $r$.