# Beltrami identity and E-L equation incompatible?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

$\newcommand{\dd}[2]{\frac{\partial {#1}}{\partial {#2}}}$
$\newcommand{\DD}[2]{\frac{d {#1}}{d {#2}}}$

Begin with the Euler-Lagrange equation $\dd Ly = \DD \ x [\dd L {y'}]$ where $L=L(y,y',x)$, (implicit dependence on $x$, so $\dd L x= 0$).

We get $\DD \ x L = \dd L {y'} y'' + \dd L y y' + [\dd L x = 0] \\= \DD \ x [\dd L {y'} y']$

so $$L - \dd L{y'}y'=Const.$$

This is a well known result.

My problem follows in this math:

$\dd L y = \dd \ y (\dd L {y'} y') =\dd { (\dd L {y'} )} y y' *$ From the equation just derived

but it also equals from the E-L equations
$\dd L y=\DD \ x \dd L {y'} = \dd {\dd L {y'}} y y' + \dd {\dd L {y'}} {y'} y'' + [\dd {\dd L {y'}} x = 0] *$

Setting the two starred equations (*) equal to each other, this gives
$$ \dd {\dd L {y'}} {y'} y'' =0$$

which is clearly wrong. What was the step that messed things up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EL equations and the Beltrami identity are [on-shell](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90866/2451) [relations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605829/2451). There are no reason why they should still hold after a partial differentiation wrt. a dependent variable $y$ or $y^{\prime}$.

*Example:* Let $L=\frac{1}{2}y^2$. Then $y\approx 0$ on-shell. However we are not allowed to differentiate the relation $y\approx 0$ wrt. $y$. That would lead to the contradiction $1\approx 0$.

Comment: I havent studied field theory and don't really know what on-shell means. Can you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: @Mondo Duke: I added links.

Comment: I see, doing this, I'm effectively using the 'wrong' lagrangian in the E-L equations. Next time, you might want to be more straightforward and just say that, but I guess it's good to get it in a bigger context. Thanks for the answers.